# Laravel or where

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Currently I am working on a project in Laravel but I am stuck.I want to create a SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM SPITems WHERE publisher_id=? AND feed_id=? AND (title LIKE '%?%' OR description LIKE '%?%')
```

Now I have this code:

```
$query = SPItem::orderBy('title');
if(isset($_GET['publisherID']) && is_numeric($_GET['publisherID']))
{
    $query = $query->where('publisher_id', $_GET['publisherID']);
}
if(isset($_GET['productFeedID']) && is_numeric($_GET['productFeedID']))
{
    $query = $query->where('program_id', $_GET['feedID']);
}
if(isset($_GET['search']))
{
    $query = $query->orWhere('title', 'like', '%' . $_GET['search'] . '%');
    $query = $query->where('description', 'like', '%' . $_GET['search'] . '%');
}
```

But that generates:

```
SELECT * FROM SPITems WHERE (publisher_id=? AND feed_id=?) OR (title LIKE '%?%') AND description LIKE '%?%'
```

How can I get the correct "or" order?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Check out the *Logical Grouping* section in the docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#logical-grouping

It explains how to group conditions in the WHERE clause.

It should be something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['search']))
{
    $query->where(function($query){
        $query->where('title', 'like', '%' . $_GET['search'] . '%')
              ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%' . $_GET['search'] . '%');
    });
}
```

Comment: you don't need `$query = $query...` the functions like `->where` modify the existing object. It is different from collections

Answer (score 1):

You can use whereRaw

```
SPItem::whereRaw(" publisher_id=? AND feed_id=? AND (title LIKE '%?%' OR description LIKE '%?%')", array(?,?,?,?))
```