# Laravel 4 where condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

below is my query...

```
    DB::table('sometable')
    ->join('sometable','sometable.ID','=','manytable.ID')
    ->where('manytable.SBPlan','00')
    ->where('manytable.NetStatus','0')
    ->select()->get();
```

for the above query i need one more condition

```
    ->where('manytable.Status','00')
    ->where('manytable.Status','21')
```

if `manytable.Status==00` or `manytable.Status==21` then select.. how do we fix this? i have  already tried

```
    ->orwhere('manytable.Status','00')
    ->orwhere('manytable.Status','21')
```

but did got a wrong result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
->where('manytable.SBPlan','00')
->where('manytable.NetStatus','0')
->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('manytable.Status','00')
      ->orWhere('manytable.Status','21');
    })
```

reference - [Laravel 4 eloquent WHERE with OR AND OR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995102/laravel-4-eloquent-where-with-or-and-or) / [Laravel or where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660180/laravel-or-where)