# How to get the select values from multiple rows in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form format something like below where users can select different ratings for each member using a select option.

```
 +---------+---------+----------+    
 |  Sl.No  |Members  | Rating   |    
 +------------------------------+    
 |  1      | abc     | 4        |    
 |  2      | xyz     | 4        |    
 |  3      | pqr     | 3        |    
 |  4      | jkl     | 5        |    
 +---------+---------+----------+
```

The rating is done by using `select` options with a name `name="ratings"`.

On submitting the form, how can I get the corresponding rating for each memeber in php?

```
$rating = Input::get('rating')
```

This is the traditional way to get the value form the select. But I have multiple selects for each members. So how can I get the rating for each user?

I tried to add a hidden field and append the `user_id` for each member. But still haven't got an idea about how to select the right data from the select option. What would be the best way to get the input from the users?

Comment: question is unclear to me and lacks the elements that show your efforts or the code that you are working on. Being precise would be more helpful rather than giving general and broad scenario.

Comment: can you please show your code

Comment: I made a bit of editing.

Comment: use group_concat to collect data from multiple rows

Comment: @Nick: How to do that? I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: You tagged the question with mysql but where does it come into play? Seems that based on what you're describing all data should be available in `$_POST`.

Comment: Change your selects from `name="ratings"` to `name="ratings[$user_id]"`, where `$user_id` is the member/user id. Then when you do `$rating = Input::get('rating');` you would have an array, with the member/user id as the key and the rating as the value

Comment: @Sean: When `dd($rating)`, I'm getting the 4 array values. 
How I can I know the user_id and corresponding value? could you give a markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the following html (used Members as rankings key, but could use user_id, etc) -

```
   Sl.No  |Members  | Rating
------------------------------
|  1      | abc     | <select name="rankings[abc]"><option selected>4</option></select>
|  2      | xyz     | <select name="rankings[xyz]"><option selected>4</option></select>
|  3      | pqr     | <select name="rankings[pqr]"><option selected>3</option></select>
|  4      | jkl     | <select name="rankings[jkl]"><option selected>5</option></select>
```

Then in your php

```
$rating = Input::get('rating');
foreach($rating as $user => $rate){
    echo $user.": ".$rate."<br />";
}
```

or, if you are updating their rating in mysql

```
$rating = Input::get('rating');
foreach($rating as $user => $rate){
    query -> UPDATE yourTable SET rating = $rate WHERE user_id = $user
}
```

Comment: Thanks again. This saved my day :) I've another question which I will post as a new one. Hope you would consider that too

Comment: This one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27716938/pass-an-array-to-redirectaction-in-laravel