# Pass an array to Redirect::action in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to pass an array from a function to another function in laravel.

In my `PageController.php`, I have

```
public function show($code, $id){
 //some code
  if(isset($search))
   dd($search);
}
```

and another function

```
public function search($code, $id){

//some queries 
$result = DB::table('abd')->get();
return Redirect::action('PageController@show, ['search'=>$search]);
}
```

But this returns me an error like this: `ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) 
Array to string conversion`

I'm using laravel.

Comment: You cannot pass arrays via urls. Also - you cannot pass $search to show() when you dont even accept a $search variable in your show() code.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your second code block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could maybe get it to work with passing by the URL by serialization, but I'd rather store it in a session variable. The session class has this nice method called `flash` which will keep the variable for the next request and then automatically remove it.

Also, and that's just a guess, you probably need to use the `index` action for that, since `show` needs the id of a specific resource.

```
public function search($code, $id){
    //some queries 
    $result = DB::table('abd')->get();
    Session::flash('search', $search); // or rather $result?
    return Redirect::action('PageController@index');
}

public function index($code){
    //some code
    if(Session::has('search')){
        $search = Session::get('search');
        dd($search);
    }
}
```