# Why i get every Item from Database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

this is my code:

```
 $customer = CustomerRepository::getInstance()->read($id)->first();
 $contacts = $customer->getContacts();

 $data = $contacts->where('firstname', '=', 'test' )
->orWhere('lastname', '=', 'test2')
    ->orderBy('lastname', 'asc'])->paginate(15);
```

...

```
public function getContacts()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Contact::class, 'contactable');
}
```

I only want the contacts from the customer which has the certain firstname or lastname , why i get every contact from the Database table?

**UPDATE:**
**So i found out, if i delete the `orWhere` clauses it works, but with the `orWhere` i get every contact. But how can i do it with the orWhere Clause?**

Comment: `$customer->getContacts()` <-- what does it return?

Comment: it returns only the contacts from the customer, thats right

Comment: can you apply `where` on it, is it laravel compatible? `DB::table('users')
->whereColumn([['column', '>', value] ])->get();`

Comment: ->where is a method for collections from laravel

Comment: Do you need only those customers where both first name and last name is a match?

Comment: *or sorry, firstname or lastname

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660180/laravel-or-where